# Ranking or posterior predictive distribution

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, predictive-models, ranking, recommender-system

It is not fully clear to me how to make prediction of future observations with Bayesian models. The usual approach should consist in using the posterior predictive distribution. Nonetheless, many papers associate the future occurrence of presently unobserved data with ranks.

For instance, consider the recommender system in this recent [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.1704.pdf). The authors develop an interesting Bayesian formulation of matrix factorization, where the Poisson distribution replaces the traditional Normal distribution. The latent parameters of the model are inferred through mean-field variational inference. Such a model allows for predicting future observation, in particular future item consumption by users. However, instead of deriving a posterior predictive distribution, the authors resort to ranking (Eq. 1).

Can you please clearly explain the differences between ranking and predictive posterior distribution for prediction? Also, in the case of above paper, can you please provide plausible interpretations of the posterior expectation in Eq. 1? Finally, what would the predictive posterior distribution look like?

Comment: The natural approach would be to contact directly the authors of the paper.